# Mod-Rewrite Rule - Unwanted 301 Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess, Clean URL, unwanted 301 redirect, 1AND1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224419/htaccess-clean-url-unwanted-301-redirect-1and1)

Mod_Rewrite is redirecting.

```
RewriteRule ^viewPage/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /viewPage.php?ID=$1&Title=$2 [NC,L]
```

Typing into browser:

```
www.domain/viewPage/123/abc/
```

the browser loads the page as expected but the URL has been 301 redirected to:

```
www.domain/viewPage.php?ID=123&Title=abc
```

I don't want the page to redirect from www.domain/viewPage/123/abc/ to www.domain/viewPage.php?ID=123&Title=abc.

How do I get this to work; I have a feeling this is to do with "301 Moved Permanently" status still in apache cache"?

Also, one more note. On the home laptop it is working as desired but it is breaking on the 1and1 server.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache first. 301 are aggressively cached by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome in incognito mode. That's what I'm doing for such tests. 
Under Ubuntu 10.04 my launcher is:

```
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --start-maximized --incognito %U
```

So each time I quit Chrome everything is deleted. And it's *everything* in contrary to Firefox where some stuff like DNS caching is kept and 301's are aggressively cached whether you're in private mode or not.